# how to listen for android hardware events

Tags: android, events, usb, hardware

I have a custom android application deployed in an android powered device. Now my client wants me to make adjustments so that if I take a software update in my usb , and insert in the device , the software would automatically get updated.

I made a secondary app , which I intend to use as USB port listener , and would carry on my work from there.

Is this all even possible. ? I am just 2 weeks old or so in android.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
the software would automatically get updated.
```

You have no control on Firmware of device until and unless you are on Root firmware or on you own firmware

Comment: thanks vipul . By firmware of the device you meant ? . And how can my software can get automatically updated , actually the android powered device where my app would be installed , wont have any internet. So it can't automatically install :S . 

Hence the client came up with the USB update option. In which he says when he'd connect the USB , my application should automatically update with the apk inside the usb

Comment: Which device you are trying on?Who is manufacturer your client?

Comment: I'll state very simply so that you can get a clear picture.

I want to make a hello world application , which would spring up on the tablet the moment I connect a standard USB to the tablet. 

Is this possible ? . 

My usb would be a normal Kingston Datatraveller.